How to access best LP node solution in branch and bound tree in CPLEX?
I am running a MIP for a finite time and it terminates with a non-zero gap. I want to access the solution (the decision variables and the objective) of the best LP relaxation (best lower bound for a minimization problem) so that I can think of ways to add/generate valid inequalities. Is there a way to get this information.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Here's what I tried so far.

I've tried the NodeCallback which helps find the objective function estimates but it does not help get the values of the decision variables.
ControlCallback seems to give this information for all nodes, but I don't know how to find it for nodes that are active/best node (node with the lowest LP objective). It also slows down the code.
MIPCallback seems to give information only on the incumbent (integer) solution.


The function get_relaxation_point() returns the optimal solution to the current LP relaxation.
See example https://github.com/PhilippeCouronne/docplex_contribs/blob/master/docplex_contribs/src/docplex_gencb.py
for j in self.locations:
            for c in self.clients:
                s, o = context.get_relaxation_point(
                    [self.supply_indices[c, j], self.used_indices[j]])

